# php fopen returns false but file is readable/writable

Tags: php

have a file that is readable and writable but fopen is returning false...

```
if(is_readable($file)) echo 'readable ';
if(is_writable($file)) echo 'writable ';
$fp = fopen($file, 'a+');
var_dump($fp);
```

result is

```
readable writable bool(false)
```

Any ideas?

sure it must be a permission thing but tried 777 on the file with same results.

Comment: Are you 1000% sure it's a file and not a directory? What does `error_reporting(E_ALL);` say?

Comment: 1000% seems a bit overkill ;P

Comment: Set error reporting to E_WARNING and see what the error message is.

Comment: I am 1googol % sure its a file

Comment: Which version of php do you use? operating system? The file is within the local filesystem (no additional url_wrapper needed)?

Comment: 1000% is "practically" impossible :D

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let's try to get more information.
What does

```
$file = 'p:\muh';

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
echo 'phpversion: ', phpversion(), "\n";
echo 'uname: ', php_uname("s r"), "\n"; // name/release of the operating system
echo 'sapi: ', php_sapi(), "\n";

echo $file, file_exists($file) ? ' exists' : ' does not exist', "\n";
echo $file, is_readable($file) ? ' is readable' : ' is NOT readable', "\n";
echo $file, is_writable($file) ? ' is writable' : ' is NOT writable', "\n";

$fp = fopen($file, 'a+');
if ( !$fp ) {
  echo 'last error: ';
  var_dump(error_get_last());
}
else {
  echo "ok.\n";
}
```

print?

see also: http://docs.php.net/error_get_last

Comment: it was a plugin that handling errors - just reporting it could not access the file - the issue was permissions as owner of file did not allow php to chmod - and that error was being surpressed...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, it was as simple as making sure the file is:

```
C:\route\to\file\filename.EXTENSION
```

In my case I was just missing the .PDF extension, so it was interpreting the name of the file as another subdirectory.