# PHP fopen doesn't work although file checks as writable

Tags: php, fopen

Helping a friend with an issue he's having.  His site is using a fopen function to open a file and save the changes to it but the fopen is failing with a "Permission Denied" error.  The file is on a remote server and permissions seem to be correct.

The code he is using is...

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
$filepath = "string.txt";
    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        $file = fopen($filepath, "w+");
        fwrite($file, $_POST['save']);
        fclose($file);
    }
}
```

I used VolkerK's code here [php fopen returns false but file is readable/writable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667466/php-fopen-returns-false-but-file-is-readable-writable) to ascertain the read/write permissions and get the following.

> PHP Version: 5.4.9
>   Uname: Windows NT
>   {File} exists
>   {File} is readable
>   {File} is writable
>   Last error: array(4){["type']=>int(2)["message"]=>string(131 "fopen({file}):failed to open stream: Permission denied.

At first I thought it was a file permissions problem but I think if the file is being seen by PHP as writable this should not be the issue, do I read that correctly?

Comment: Ran a quick test on win7 and this works for me. The file is written with the contents of the $_POST variable. Try with a fresh *.txt file.

Comment: You say the file is on a remote server, it might be that [`allow_url_fopen`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) _might_ be false - though I'm not sure that would be the problem, it is worth looking in to. Other than that, the code runs as-is, so we would need more context on the remote server and the `$filepath` being used.

Comment: If it's a remote file, what protocol are you using?

Comment: It's http.  Maybe I should try ftp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried FTP and got there.  Had to properly set context options for FTP connection though.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
//Setup FTP connection
$ftp = "ftp://user:password@example.com/filepath/filename.txt";
//Set FTP Options
$stream_options = array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true));
$stream_context = stream_context_create($stream_options);
//Open file and write changes
if (file_exists($ftp)) {
    $file = fopen($ftp, "w", 0 , $stream_context);
    fwrite($file, $_POST['save']);
    fclose($file);
    }
}
```