# php cannot create file

Tags: php, html

I've installed myself a LAMP according to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04). Mine is Ubuntu 17.10 instead of 16.04, but I can't see that it should make a difference.

I've setup ownership and permissions according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/767534/4246).

This is my index.php:

```
<?php
  if($_POST['statusFormSubmit'] == "Submit")
  {
  alert("in php");
  $varStatus = $_POST['statusInput'];
  alert("$varStatus");
  $path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mydata.csv';
  $fs = fopen($path, "a");
  alert("file $path");
  fwrite($fs, $varStatus . ", " . $varStatus . "\n");
  fclose($fs);
  header("Location: thankyou.html");
  exit;
  }

  function alert($msg) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";
}
?>

<html>
  <head >
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <title >Form page: status</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Your status:</h1>

    <form id='form_status' method='post' action='index.php' >
      <p>
        <input type='text' name='statusInput' maxlength="140" value="<?=$varStatus;?>">
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type='submit' name='statusFormSubmit' value='Submit' />
      </p>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

and thankyou.html, if you must see it. Here:

```
<html>
  Thank you for submitting!
</html>
```

I open `localhost/index.php` in my browser, I fill in the field with typically "asdf", get to the thank you page... but no file is created. Where is it going wrong?

Incidentally, the javascript alerts don't show up either (I think they did when I had the files somewhere else, that is without apache involved). Any explanation for this would also be welcome.

---

Adding more debug info with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3668006/108802), I get that the path does not exist (correct), is not readable nor writable (seems logical then)

```
Warning: fopen(/var/www/html/mydata.csv): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/index.php on line 18
last error: array(4) { ["type"]=> int(2) ["message"]=> string(73) "fopen(/var/www/html/mydata.csv): failed to open stream: Permission denied" ["file"]=> string(23) "/var/www/html/index.php" ["line"]=> int(18) }
```

The permissions I have for the path are (snipped):

```
$ ll /
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root 4.0K Mar 13 15:32 var/

$ ll /var
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4.0K Mar 18 17:01 www/

$ ll /var/www
drwxr-sr-x 2 gauthier www-data 4.0K Mar 22 22:08 html/
```

There we have it, the group has no write permission, which I guess is what apache needs to create the file.

What is the correct way to do it, give `g+w`? Create the files in the directory? Other?

Comment: Check what `fwrites` returns.

Comment: @revo: of course, I always check for... That would be silly of me not to...mrmmm... That's embarassing. I'll edit my question.